# Android: Butter knife unable to find and cast the corresponding views in layout

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0, butterknife

I am using ButterKnief for the first time so as per [documentation](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

I am trying to bind my text view and on-click of button change it's text, but its not working because butterknife is even unable to find the view(getting a null)

MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.text_view_butter) private TextView text;
    static int count;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        Log.d("Tag","");
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_butterKnife)
    public void submit()
    {
        text.setText("You presed me "+count+" times");
    }
}
```

dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.0'
}
```

Layout File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.worldline.butterknifetest.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_butter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_butterKnife"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ButterKnife me"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_butter"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="77dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any Idea what might be the missing block here?

Comment: use ButterKnife.inject(this) instead of ButterKnife.bind

Comment: Change @BindView(R.id.text_view_butter) private TextView text; to @InjectView(R.id.text_view_butter) TextView text. Please note that ButterKnife doesn't work with access modifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added this line to your dependencies( I donot see it ) in your gradle.build file:

```
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.0'
```

**The runtime and compiler are now split into two artifacts.**

See more here https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: No -> compile com.jakewharton:butterknife:**8.0.0**

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to build.gradle(app) resolved it

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.0'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.0'
}
```